# if there are two records for same id ,then get only one record based on below condition

Tags: oracle

![enter image description here][1]

if there are two records for same id ,then get only one record based on below condition.

e.g.
[image: Source and Expected]

i) If I get 2 null data in a column for same id, then pass null.

ii) If I get 2 same not null data in a column for same id, then pass not null.

ii) If I get 1 null and 1 not null data in a column for same id, then pass not null.

ii) If I get 2 different not null data in a column for same id, then pass '?'.

Please find the data in source.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ehh..what is your question?

Comment: suppose if i have 2 values for same id column in a table, i need to standardize based on the condition given in the question.

Comment: What if you get 3 or 4 or 162 for the same ID?

Comment: I just gave an example. It can be 5 or 10 also. I need to pass null, if get only null for an id.

ii) If I get 2 same not null data in a column for same id, then pass not null.

ii) If I get 1 null and 1 not null data in a column for same id, then pass not null.

ii) If I get 2 different not null data in a column for same id, then pass '?'.

Comment: Can you post some sample data and expected output

Comment: Please find the source records for same id column in the image attached along with the question.

Comment: If you see the image, the BUS_NATURE_DE has 2 different not null values for same id in the source table. So i need pass '?'  to the target for this scenario. Like wise, for TOT_ASSET_AM I need to pass the not null value out those null and not null.

Comment: anyone have any idea ?